# Как правильно ставить скобки?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Вопрос: если выражение, заключенное в скобки, содержит другое выражение или слово, заключенное в скобки, ставятся ли две закрывающие скобки рядом (или одна)?

Пример: *некто пошел на прогулку (он всегда это делал до обеда (либо после обеда)).*

Правильно ли такое написание?

Answer (score 1):

Вложенных скобок следует избегать. Во всяком случае указаний на возможность их применения в каком-либо контексте я не встречал.
Но из общих соображений - одна. Так же поступают, когда по техническим причинам невозможно использование разных типов кавычек.

---

Вот про кавычки.

*Плюс от Мильчина, "Справочник издателя и автора", раздел 8.2.4:

Если по техническим причинам невозможен набор кавычек разного рисунка, кавычки одного рисунка рядом не повторяются. Напр.: "Цыганы" мои не продаются вовсе", -- сетовал Пушкин.*

Перецитировано с форума Грамоты, под рукой нет первоисточника, но когда-то давно проверял. Считаю, что здесь прослеживается вполне естественное требование при наборе никогда не повторять рядом два пунктуационных знака (кроме оговоренных случаев "тройной" точки, вопросительного и восклицательного знаков, что рассматривается как единый знак).
Эту логику я переношу на случай со скобками.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, мне кажется, что такое может быть, только выглядит как-то не слишком красиво. Попробуйте как-то перестроить предложение, например: "(он всегда это делал до обеда, а иногда - после)"

Answer (score 0):

Круглые скобки - парный знак препинания. Они используются при необходимости выделения в предложении вставных конструкций. Информацию в круглых скобках можно легко удалить из предложения или наоборот добавить, при этом не изменяя смысла. Если вставная конструкция, заключенная в скобки, содержит еще одну конструкцию, заключенную в скобки, ставятся рядом две закрывающие скобки. Но во избежание нагромождения одинаковых знаков препинания скобки (одну из пар) можно заменить на тире или запятые. В вашем примере высказывание можно даже разделить на два предложения: Некто пошел на прогулку. Он всегда это делал до обеда (либо после обеда).

Comment: Интересно, это авторитетный источник?

Comment: Отсюда?
http://www.englishelp.ru/learn-english/articles-for-learners/303-dashes-parentheses-commas.html

Это статья "широко неизвестного" автора, посвященная оформлению статей на английском языке.

Comment: Что касается кавычек, то да, рекомендуется использовать разные типы кавычек, а при использовании одинаковых - писать только одну. А вот использовать разные типы скобок в русском языке не принято. Каких-то правил, описывающих подобные примеры, не нашла, отвечаю на основании опыта. Кстати, при в программировании отстутствие закрывающей скобки - синтаксическая ошибка (правда, там можно использовать скобки разного типа).

Comment: Это на каком же языке??? Сорок лет программирую - никогда о разных типах не слыхивал. В программировании отсутсвие скобки, конечно же, всегда было ошибкой.
Но в любом случае, к сожалению или к счастью, перенос понятий из программирования на живой язык неправомерно.

Comment: Я дополнил свой ответ соображения про кавычки: *Плюс от Мильчина...*, 
посмотрите, пожалуйста, в комментариях не помещается.